# SQL Repeated Condition in Two Tables

Tags: sql, variables, coding-style, conditional-statements

I am a beginner to SQL, and I am having trouble getting rid of repeated code. I have a condition "AccountId=20" that I use twice in a SQL query. The SQL looks something like:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE FunctionId IN (Select FunctionId FROM Table_B WHERE AccountId=20);
DELETE FROM Table_B WHERE AccountId=20;
```

When I change the condition, I have to change both lines in the code.

I want to clean up the repeated code. I have tried something like:

```
DECLARE @condition datatypeForConditions = AccountId=20;
DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE FunctionId IN (Select FunctionId FROM Table_B WHERE @condition);
DELETE FROM Table_B WHERE @condition;
```

SQL does not seem to have a datatype for conditions, so I cannot declare this variable. Can I even set a variable for a condition?  How can I avoid having to change the condition in two places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it like this

```
DECLARE @AccountId int;
@AccountID=20;
DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE FunctionId IN (Select FunctionId FROM Table_B WHERE AccountID=@AccountId);
DELETE FROM Table_B WHERE AccountID=@AccountId;
```